# LIBSVM Probability estimates in binary classification

Tags: probability, libsvm

I have Training data like the following :

```
1 1:128.319 2:71.4336 3:130.255 4:292.948 5:96.3541 6:71.942 7:136.189 8:71.5032 9:148.21 10:304.011 11:90.3781 12:99.4496 13:164.268 14:138.892 15:220.871 16:139.198 17:151.709
1 1:118.431 2:97.5874 3:92.0313 4:242.383 5:32.5916 6:91.4476 7:122.88 8:86.6046 9:104.173 10:278.208 11:100.356 12:44.0638 13:159.678 14:163.307 15:181.011 16:83.5148 17:96.1238
1 1:137.925 2:103.664 3:129.569 4:280.765 5:48.4616 6:93.4706 7:104.143 8:87.889 9:125.967 10:284.253 11:80.2913 12:51.7028 13:125.539 14:162.068 15:203.335 16:175.856 17:177.638
1 1:134.952 2:141.661 3:247.987 4:288.032 5:41.1806 6:109.573 7:117.331 8:99.5418 9:159.184 10:232.882 11:78.1744 12:75.0752 13:168.181 14:132.876 15:204.355 16:107.003 17:118.515
0 1:115.603 2:61.5781 3:132.382 4:293.832 5:65.9111 6:106.214 7:103.853 8:116.03 9:142.142 10:293.42 11:49.4609 12:97.0318 13:157.035 14:146.374 15:179.402 16:135.535 17:125.605
0 1:128.367 2:68.9784 3:83.4542 4:233.359 5:71.6529 6:69.5444 7:134.49 8:64.3986 9:87.4766 10:282.327 11:87.1273 12:61.7704 13:136.858 14:131.094 15:164.514 16:68.9703 17:70.6821
0 1:109.747 2:85.5685 3:139.116 4:309.536 5:53.0768 6:93.8608 7:100.835 8:87.8225 9:131.276 10:277.85 11:93.1516 12:49.7809 13:163.615 14:148.949 15:236.783 16:148.671 17:186.764
0 1:112.509 2:79.2363 3:153.702 4:271.478 5:74.3454 6:86.4557 7:86.2066 8:84.2486 9:156.918 10:254.445 11:74.8842 12:75.8982 13:112.379 14:108.054 15:164.201 16:84.1002 17:102.252
0 1:141.522 2:78.2754 3:127.487 4:363.352 5:91.2171 6:81.9828 7:231.043 8:113.83 9:229.079 10:437.796 11:122.712 12:115.435 13:178.213 14:155.286 15:188.521 16:131.901 17:124.573
```

And when i run the following code:

```
[true_label, data_inst] = libsvmread('C:\Users\fypstudent\Documents\MATLAB\Training_Data\OVA_E0.txt');
model = svmtrain(true_label, data_inst, '-c 1 -g 0.07 -t 0 -b 1');
[true_label, data_inst] = libsvmread('C:\Users\fypstudent\Documents\MATLAB\Training_Data\OVA_E0.txt');
[predict_label, accuracy, prob_estimates] = svmpredict(true_label, data_inst, model, '-b 1');
```

I get the following probabilities for the data I provided:

```
0.145614770432359   0.854385229567641
0.146701861245572   0.853298138754428
0.146126482529063   0.853873517470937
0.148072155086074   0.851927844913926
0.147143517011699   0.852856482988301
0.145711409800836   0.854288590199164
0.144862609974806   0.855137390025194
0.145741700456742   0.854258299543258
0.146935964238630   0.853064035761370
```

I like to know what these probabilities indicate.  I also get probability > 0.5 for false labels, can someone help me in understanding this?

Answer (score 3):

The probabilities returned, iirc, are $P(f(x)=1)$ in the first column and $P(f(x)=-1)$ in the second. Your model seems to predict everything as negative. Based on eyeballing your data, this can be caused by the fact you didn't normalize. If you don't want to normalize (*you really should*), you will probably need to increase `c`.

Not directly related to the question, but why are you providing a gamma value (`-g 0.07`) when you use the linear kernel (`-t 0`)?